# How can I add custom fields to the article component?

Tags: content

As per the title, how can I add custom fields to the article component?

The tutorial, http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component almost gets there and it a beautiful piece of work, but relies on a core patch that was never accepted into core.

So I guess I could do that myself, but it means a hack.  Or I could install an extension.

Any other ways?  What do most people do?

Comment: +1 Definitely think this should be turned into a Wiki. There a few answers out there, some good, some bad, but it would be nice to refer back to this whenever someone else asks or for personal future reference.

Comment: Check out the Content Construction category on JED, there are some promising extensions. Maybe [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/10667) or [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction/22188)

Comment: You can use this approach: http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin and save in images for instance.

Comment: @Peter Lose Sadly that link is only fleshed out for com_contact which will have been been written to support the addition of fields in this simplified way. But thanks for the suggestion - I was only aware that user profiles supported extension using a similar method.  Unfortunately com_content doesn't appear to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save Custom Fields in Core components](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components)

Comment: @GDP As per my response to Peter Lose, the article you referenced is for com_contact, not com_content.  The com_contact component has support for optional fields, but the com_content component doesn't, hence the article I initially referenced, and the core patch that was never implemented.

Comment: If you look at the link I provided, you will see that I did what you're asking for articles.

Answer (score 4):

The exact steps to do this for #__content are given at [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components).  The main difference for articles that makes the original tutorial unusuable is that articles do not have the params column, but the attribs column instead.

Answer (score 2):

@Peter you can store your custom fields in the images field in the com_content table. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
  <fields name="images">
    <field name="spacer2" type="spacer" hr="true" />
            <field name="test" type="text" />
  </fields>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use this cck.

http://www.aixeena.org/aixeena-lab/aixeena-easy-cck

It allows to add fields to joomla article in a very non-intrusive way.