# Adding Custom Fields to Article Component [Not in attribs field]

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, jform, com-content, custom-action

I am trying to save some additional fields into the Article Content and there has been a few questions like [this](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/2395/112) relating to this issue but all of the solutions seem to point to saving the extra field into the 'attribs' column but since this VARCHAR column has a Length of '5120' characters; it won't be enough for what I need.

So I was trying to save into a separate table following [this article](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component) but it won't work since it is also saving into the attribs column and not in the table it mentions in Joomla 3.x.

Someone asked [similar question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/how-can-i-add-custom-fields-to-the-article-component) which doesn't have any answer except save it in the 'attribs' column (even with the plugin). So is there no way to save custom fields into a separate table without using a full on CCKs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using FieldsAttatch for this, see http://www.fieldsattach.com/ for more info.

It is not a full on CCK, but a much lighter system that allows you to add fields to the Joomla content model in a simple an elegant way.  The fields Augment the standard joomla content fields and are just editable for the user in or more tabs.

Comment: I have tried it before and I have had some bad experience with it. While it does what I want, it seems to be too big for what I am looking for. Also when I had to uninstall it, it was a real pain.

I managed to use the 'images' field since that column is 'TEXT' type while the attribs is not [it's varchar with the size of around 5200]. It was pretty straightforward and required no core hacks.

Here is something similar for reference: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3778/112

Answer (score 4):

I've been using FieldsAttach for this sort of thing, for a few years, the the concepts are clean and eloquent. Brian Teeman explains it well from an integrator point of view in his talk at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2WLKWbRj5U but in some ways it is even more compelling from a developer's perspective.

However, after watching Marco Ding's Joomla Day UK 2016 talk on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDh1IPuZAVA I think DPFields may be a better choice. The architecture is perhaps more rugged and neater, but also because it may well end up being a core extension in Joomla in the near future. More info on DPFields is at http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/dpfields , https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields and https://joomla.digital-peak.com/documentation/162-dpfields .