# Joomla Custom Fields Module / Matrix

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field

I'm new to Joomla...wondering if there's a module similar to [ExpressionEngine matrix fields](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix).

Ultimately, I would like the ability to create a set of grouped custom fields where user can add multiple groups and edit those specific fields, rather than editing an entire Custom HTML field.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options for this, the two best are probably FieldsAttatch and DPFields.

I've used FieldsAttatch for a few years, and it has a nice light approach.  However the newer DPFields looks good and is, in some ways, a more elegant architecture.

DPFields is probably the best option.

There is a similar question at...
[Adding Custom Fields to Article Component [Not in attribs field]](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13557)

Some useful links...

- FieldsAttatch: http://www.fieldsattach.com/
- DPFields:
  https://joomla.digital-peak.com/products/dpfields
- Brian Teeman on
  FieldsAttatch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2WLKWbRj5U
- Marco
  Dings on DPFields: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDh1IPuZAVA