# Custom content plugin not saving data when conditionally restricted to single page

Tags: com-content

I have written a simple plugin to include custom content against Joomla articles. Here's the code:

```
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access' );

class plgContentHomegrid extends JPlugin {

    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {

        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');

        switch($option) {

            case 'com_content':
                if ($app->isAdmin()) {

                    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');

                        $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);

                }

                return true;

        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

This works fine, the additional fields are displayed as a separate tab in admin, data saves correctly and everything's perfect. So far so good...however, I only want to display the additional tab on the home page. So, I amended the code so the additional form is only displayed for the home page:

```
 if( $data->featured == 1 ){

    $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);

}
```

The form now only displays on the home page admin screen as needed BUT the data is not saved.

This is partially explained by [this issue](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/content-plugin-loadfile-loads-conditional-form-data-but-does-not-save-the-data), but I'm not clear how I can amend the code so that the form is conditionally displayed AND saved.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: (Seems this thread is a DIY one...)
Got it....

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$formData = new JInput($input->get('jform', '', 'array'));

if( $data->featured == 1 || $formData->getInt('featured', 0) == 1){

   $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);

}
```

Does the trick.

Comment: I would use Joomla's `JInput`, not `$_POST`

Comment: Thanks for your response. How exactly do I access the data using JInput? Tried multiple approaches but none worked.

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question, and show some code, so it will be easier to assist you

Comment: Well, the code is above. The question relates to the original problem and it seems to me it would not be sensible to split the answer into two. I don't see how to access the Jinput object to access the posted data.How do I access the 'featured' posted data from JInput?

Comment: As mentioned before, this is a separate topic, so please ask a new question ;)

Comment: It's not a separate topic. My original question said how do I amend my code so that the data is saved, but forget it, I've solved it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered your question by yourself. This is just an answer to show you how to get the data with JInput:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

if ($data->featured == 1 || $input->getInt('featured') == 1)
{
   $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);
}
```

or

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

if ($data->featured == 1 || $input->getInt('Itemid') == 100)
{
   $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);
}
```

(where "100" is your menu item ID of the home menu item)