# Custom fields in com_content does not display when editing article in front end

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, form, custom-field

I created a plugin to add a custom field following this [answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/2395/112). Works fine when I am logged in the backend and edit the article but the tab is not displaying when the article is being edited from the front. Am I missing something here or do I have to do it like the docs mention [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component)

Plugin XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="attribs" >
        <fieldset name="custom" >
            <field name="full_article_image_overlay"
                type="editor"
                filter="safehtml"
                buttons="true"
                label="PLG_FULL_ARTILCE_IMAGE_TEXT"
                />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
</form>
```

Plugin PHP:

```
function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {

        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');

        switch($option) {

            case 'com_content':
                if ($app->isAdmin()) {
                        JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                        //Show specific forms based on categories
                        $form->loadFile('content', false);
                }
                return true;

        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Stored Data in 'attribs' column

```
{
  "show_title": "",
  "link_titles": "",
  "show_tags": "",
  "show_intro": "",
  "info_block_position": "",
  "show_category": "",
  "link_category": "",
  "show_parent_category": "",
  "link_parent_category": "",
  "show_author": "",
  "link_author": "",
  "show_create_date": "",
  "show_modify_date": "",
  "show_publish_date": "",
  "show_item_navigation": "",
  "show_icons": "",
  "show_print_icon": "",
  "show_email_icon": "",
  "show_vote": "",
  "show_hits": "",
  "show_noauth": "",
  "urls_position": "",
  "alternative_readmore": "",
  "article_layout": "",
  "show_publishing_options": "",
  "show_article_options": "",
  "show_urls_images_backend": "",
  "show_urls_images_frontend": "",
  "full_article_image_overlay": "<p>Test Test<\/p>"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In front article edit form there are only selected fields added. If you want to add something there you will have to use [Template Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) to edit this file: `/components/com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php`. This component for now does not load custom form fields automatically like com_content does.

#### Adding field in form.php layout of article view

If you have your data stored in attribs field (params fieldset in form) something like this should work:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('YOUR_FIEL_DNAME', 'params'); ?>
```

#### Adding field field into article form object by plugin

To add custom field to Article Form you can use this tutorial:
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin
But remember that you still have to add proper field in the view.

Comment: Thanks for that but I can't seem to find the 'attribs' in the JForm Object and since the extra field I have is stored in the 'attribs' column, would I need some more code unlike the backend where I simply created the field? Any pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Tried doing this:

<?php echo $this->form->renderField('full_article_image_overlay', 'params'; ?>

Edit: Sorry added that by mistake as I hit enter before completing. But the above code return empty when var_dumped. Attaching the plugin code now.

Comment: I don't understand. Why did you added this JSON after? Also it would be good for you to add your plugin code and form XML code into question.

Comment: Updated the question with relevant code.

Comment: Try to change `attribs` fieldname into `params`. There is no `attribs` fieldset in original form so it is not processed by the model. Also you didn't read this link: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin it shows how xml form should be build.

Comment: Forgot to update that I used tried both 'attribs' and 'params'. In the forms beyond 3.2, we can't use 'params' but use 'attribs' instead according to this answer: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/2397/112

Comment: As I see front form/article models do not store attribs/params field at all. But `images` fieldset is saved, Maybe try to use that one instead of ? I'm not sure how it will affect backend but its worth a try.

Comment: I guess I will just have to store in a separate table following. https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component