# How to add a field to com_content in the backend?

Tags: plugin, joomla-3.9

I'm confused about this. I want to add a field to the com_content core component that needs to show up under the "Title" field in the administrator backend when you edit an article and of course to be it accessible site-wise in the front end in the article object.

I found this official tutorial: [**Adding custom fields to core components using a plugin**](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin), 
where it talks about the front end editing?

In fact it says to override the `/components/com_contact/views/form/tmpl/edit.php` when the editing part in the backend happens in `/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php` and I'm not sure if the backend even reads the `/components/com_contact/views/form/tmpl/edit.xml` that is supposed to add the field in the database.

So is there a tutorial that could help me achieve that? 
I'm using joomla 3.9

Note: I don't want to use the custom field feature.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. While you wait for support, please take the [tour] and have look through some of the other component or plugin tagged questions.

Comment: The tutorial you follow uses another component as an example and not the com_content. So follow that tutorial but adjust your code for the com_content. This might also be helpful https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components - and I believe there should be more similar questions/answers in this site to search and find help.

Comment: I am not sure if this question can have an answer - Sandro please can you confirm that you can follow the said tutorial so we can close this question... and you can come back to ask another question if you need specific help on something? Also @mickmackusa to be notified about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I put the edit.xml inside the override folder instead I needed to put it inside the plugin folder.

Comment: Good on you for posting a clear resolution -- even if it was a minor oversight on your behalf, there is always the chance that someone else may have the exact same issue.  Again, please earn your Informed badge by taking the [tour].